# Missing some cookies on NSURLRequest after changing to WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest, nshttpcookie

I am in the process of replacing `UIWebView` in our app with `WKWebView` and I have run into a cookie problem. There is a login process in our app where a webform is shown in a web view, and if the login was successful we call a service that gives us our auth token. The service recognises a successful login by a session cookie that was set in the web view. With `UIWebView` we didn't need to do anything to pass this cookie to the token request since both `UIWebView` and `NSURLSession` use the shared `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. `WKWebView` however doesn't use the shared cooke storage, so I copy all cookies from it to the shared storage before calling the token service:

```
[webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray* cookies) {
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
    }
}];
```

This seem to work if I print out the cookies in the shared storage

```
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookies) {
    NSLog(@"name: %@\tvalue: %@", cookie.name, cookie.value);
}
```

I get this:

```
name: mobile                                            value: 220|220
name: BDJSESSIONID                                      value: 0000YHfKy0d8aGHsOKPZBFznsQt:bdaix570
name: vp                                                value: ourdomain-com
name: ukontrol                                          value: nb8sfm1:1590215000215:
name: ACENBP                                            value: ffffffffc3a01a5945525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660
name: clientsession                                     value: NaN
name: _ga                                               value: GA1.2.2108673536.1590134296
name: _gid                                              value: GA1.2.570415333.1590134296
name: xLocale                                           value: da:DK
name: _gat_UA-56861410-1                                value: 1
name: PD_STATEFUL_c57e342c-fccf-4a0c-bb38-de5e09832f2c  value: %2Fcardapp.services
name: PD_STATEFUL_00819ac9-1bb8-4375-80ff-00c0285bab51  value: %2Fcardapp.services
```

This looks exactly the same as when I use a `UIWebView`.
The `BDJSESSIONID` cookie is the important one here. If I am missing that, the call to the token service will create a new session, where the user is not logged in.

My problem now is that some of the cookies (including `BDJSESSIONID`) are missing when I call the token service like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLSessionTask *sessionTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    ...
}];
[sessionTask resume];
```

These are the cookies actually sent:

[image]

I should note that the code for calling the token service was not changed from when we were using `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage) documenttion mentions following points:

> - UIWebView - UIWebView instances within an app inherit the parent app's shared cookie storage.
> - [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) - Each WKWebView instance has its own cookie storage. See the [WKHTTPCookieStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkhttpcookiestore) class for more information.

So the cookies you are adding to shared `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, will not be directly available in your WKWebView.
Instead, you should set cookies in your [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)'s [WKHTTPCookieStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkhttpcookiestore):

```
[[[[webView configuration] websiteDataStore] httpCookieStore] setCookie:cookie completionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Added cookie: %@", cookie);
}];
```

Comment: I realize all this, as I have described in my question. Also, my issue goes the other way around - I need to copy cookies FROM `WKWebView` to the shared storage so that they can be used a `NSURLSession`.

Comment: @pajevic I'm facing the same problem presently. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @geohei No, we ended up using a different solution altogether.